# Lucene : Use SpanTermQuery to get results for words with special characters

Tags: java, lucene

Is it possible to search for results in Lucene for non-character words, for example if I am trying to find results for "word-processing" or "foo-bar". It doesn't look like they are considered as single term, while using SpanTermQuery.  I get results for it using QueryParser but not SpanTermQuery. I am just wondering how it works, Any comments/ Ideas on how to have SpanTermQuery work for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at how your field's Tokenizers and Analyzers are configured. Read the javadocs for the existing out of the box Tokenizers/Analyzers to see if one of them meet your needs. If one doesn't meet your needs, it's pretty easy to extend and create your own Tokenizer and/or Analyzer.

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_do_I_write_my_own_Analyzer.3F
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Tokenizer.html